# Capture output from a PowerShell command in a batch file's for /f loop

Tags: powershell, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, syntax

This PowerShell code selects the correct value for `var5` from this string. The desired result it "Alert Raised".

```
PS C:\src\t> $s = 'Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March'
PS C:\src\t> $s
Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March
PS C:\src\t> $s | Where-Object { $_ -match '.*var5=(.*)\s+\w+:' } | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] }
Alert Raised
```

However, using the same powershell code in a cmd shell script produces a different result. Why is that? Is there something that needs to be escaped for the cmd shell?

```
C:>type mat002-annex.bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "S=Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March"
ECHO S is set to %S
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    " '%S%' | Where-Object { $_ -match '.*var5=(.*)\s+\w+:' } | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] } "') DO (ECHO Result is "%%a")

C:>mat002-annex.bat
S is set to S
Result is "Alert"
```

Comment: `for /?`: *By default, `/F` passes the **first blank separated token** from each line of each file.*

Comment: @PetSerAl - Yes. Spot on. I need "tokens=*".

Comment: Why? Dispense with the batch file and use PowerShell directly.

Comment: I agree that it would be good to move to PowerShell. Not every organization or manager is ready to do that.

Comment: PowerShell has been available for over 10 years now and has been a built-in part of the operating system since Windows 7. Make the switch; it is worth the investment.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - I am already convinced. I am not the one who makes such a decision. I do when I can. PowerShell 3, released the month before 2012, was workable. Perhaps your claim should be that it was usable five (5) years ago.

Comment: Decision about what? Nothing is stopping you from using it. It's part of the OS and has been for quite some time. (And in fact you are already using it--just with the unnecessary complication of calling it from `cmd.exe`.)

Comment: Perhaps you do not work in an organization with managers and software development standards. I would write much more PowerShell if it were permitted.

Comment: The questions posted here might also find a PowerShell solution rejected. Making it fit into a cmd space is one way of getting exposure.

Comment: My point is _you are using PowerShell already_ (albeit in a roudabout and difficult-to-use way)--so why not dispense with the complication and use it directly? Hopefully pointing this out will help you in your organization. Good luck.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - I am thinking of the OP's organization. I am also trying not to get ragged on and voted down for providing a PowerShell solution to a cmd question. Yes, they are out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as he often does, has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

**`cmd.exe`'s `for /f` loop by default breaks its input lines into tokens *by whitespace***, so that `for /f %%a in (...) do` only places the *first* such token in variable `%%a`.

This **default behavior can be modified with an *options string***: `for /f "<options>" %%a in (...) do`.
Running `for /?` from a `cmd.exe` prompt describes its syntax:

```
    eol=c           - specifies an end of line comment character
                      (just one)
    skip=n          - specifies the number of lines to skip at the
                      beginning of the file.
    delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
                      default delimiter set of space and tab.
    tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
                      be passed to the for body for each iteration.
                      This will cause additional variable names to
                      be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
                      specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
                      the last character in the tokens= string is an
                      asterisk, then an additional variable is
                      allocated and receives the remaining text on
                      the line after the last token parsed.
    usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
                      where a back quoted string is executed as a
                      command and a single quoted string is a
                      literal string command and allows the use of
                      double quotes to quote file names in
                      file-set.
```

---

#### If you want each input line to be captured in a *single* variable, you have two options:

Note: The **examples below use the following PowerShell command line**, which simply outputs a string literal with multiple leading, inner, and trailing spaces,    `one   two`   .

```
powershell -command " '   one   two   ' "
```

To make quoting easier, option `usebackq` is used below, which allows embedding the command in `` `...` ``.

Also note that it's **good practice to add `-NoProfile` to `powershell.exe`'s command line** to prevent unnecessary - and potentially behavior-changing - loading of a user's profile; I've omitted it below for brevity.

---

##### `"delims="`: preserving the line *exactly as-is*

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`powershell -command " '   one   two   ' "`) do echo Result is "%%a"
```

The above yields:

```
Result is "   one   two   "
```

Note how the leading and trailing spaces were preserved too.

**Important**: for **`delims=`** to be recognized as *deactivating* delimiter-based (separator-based) parsing, it **must be placed *at the very end* of the options string.**

---

##### `"tokens=*"`: trimming *leading* whitespace

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`powershell -command " '   one   two   ' "`) do echo Result is "%%a"
```

The above yields:

```
Result is "one   two   "
```

Note how the *leading* spaces were *trimmed*.

It is curious that the trimming is only applied to *leading* whitespace, and there appears to be no direct way to trim trailing whitespace as well.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the `for` loop in the batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "S=Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command " '%S%' | Where-Object { $_ -match '.*var5=(.*)\s+\w+:' } | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] } "
```

The above gives the expected result.

Comment: You are right that this does give the correct output to stdout. I would still need to do something to get it into a variable. PetSerAl spotted it.

Comment: Given that (as we now know more clearly) the intent is to catpure PowerShell's output in a _variable_, can I suggest you revise or delete your answer?
As an aside: While using `-NoProfile` is good practice, `-NoLogo` is unnecessary in combination with `-Command` or `-File`.