# Batch script: Pass returned GUID as URL parameter for desktop shortcut

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to create desktop shortcuts to a private page we work with that will open in Edge, direct to a specific URL, and pass the GUID as a URL parameter.

I've tried the following but as you can expect, only the string "powershell" is passed on to the URL, not the returned GUID.

```
SET a=powershell -Command "[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()"
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start msedge "https://www.website.com/page?user="%a% --no-first-run
```

How can I replace the %a% portion of the URL with the returned contents of the system GUID?

```
powershell -Command "[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:

- This answer addresses the question *as asked*: it captures the output from a PowerShell command in a batch-file variable for later use in the same batch file.
- Alternatively, the specific task at hand can also be performed *in full* by a single PowerShell command, as shown in [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614811/45375).

---

**Batch files (executed by `cmd.exe`) have *no* concept of a what is known as *command substitution* in POSIX-compatible shells** (a feature that PowerShell itself provides too, though it has no official name there): the ability to assign a command's *output* to a *variable*.<sup>[1]</sup>

Instead, **you must use a `for /f` loop to capture command output in a variable** (which generally loops over *each output line*, but in your case there is only *one* output line):

```bash
@echo off
setlocal

:: Capture the output from a PowerShell command in variable %guid%, via 
:: a for /f loop:
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`powershell -Command "[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()"`) do set "guid=%%a"

:: Note: No need for `cmd /c` from a batch file to use `start`
start "" msedge "https://www.website.com/page?user=%guid%" --no-first-run
```

<sup>Note: `setlocal`, while not strictly necessary, localizes any variable definitions to the batch file at hand.</sup>

- Run `for /?` in a `cmd.exe` session for help.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50102534/45375) discusses  using `for /f` to capture command output in more detail; notably:

  - `usebackq` isn't strictly necessary here, but is generally advisable to give you the freedom to use both `'` and `"` quoting in the command line being invoked.
  - Similarly, `delims=` isn't strictly necessary here, since the output by definition contains no *spaces*, but it is generally advisable if the intent is to capture an output line *in full*.
- The `""` as the first `start` argument isn't strictly necessary here, but in general it is useful when invoking applications whose paths must be double-quoted. Without `""` as the first argument, a double-quoted application path would be interpreted as `starts` *window-title* argument (which only meaningfully applies to *console* applications).

---

<sup>[1] In POSIX-compatible shells, use `$(...)` (e.g, `captured="$(whoami)"`). In PowerShell, you can use the command -as-is as the RHS of the assignment (e.g., `$captured = whoami`)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do all of this directly using a PowerShell one-liner:

```sh
powershell -noprofile -command start msedge \"https://www.website.com/page?user=$(New-Guid) --no-first-run\"
```

- Passing `-noprofile` to `powershell.exe` is most of the time a good idea to reduce startup time and provide a more predictable environment as no user profile will be loaded.
- `start` is an alias for the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2) command.
- Here `start` gets passed two positional arguments, the name of the process to start (`-FilePath` parameter) and the process's arguments as a single string (`-ArgumentList` parameter). Therefore, the 2nd argument must be quoted. To pass the quotes from the command processor `cmd.exe` through to PowerShell, they must be backslash-escaped.
- Within the process's parameter string, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) `$(…)` is used to call the `New-Guid` command inline and convert it to a string (by implicitly calling the `.ToString()` method of the `Guid` object it returns).
- If you actually need to use the GUID as a variable in other parts of your batch script (which is not clear from the question), then this [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614812/7571258) provides a solution.